# jQuery.noConflict() method causing problem in my App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I am using jQuery in my Rails application. I wanted to add a expand collapse text effect in my page. So I downloaded the [jQuery exapander plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/) and tried to use it. I am facing a weird problem.

My `jQuery.js` file is having this line called `jQuery.noConflict();` at the end. I have to remove it to make this expand collapse effect to work. But then, when I remove it, a calendar component that I have used somewhere else in the app is not working.

Please help me out here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) causes jQuery to relinquish control of the `$` variable. Are you using another library on the same page that also uses `$`? Does the calendar component use jQuery?

If your page has this:

```
$.noConflict();
```

Then from that point onward, `$` is not jQuery. So:

```
$('#something').expander(); // won't work
jQuery('#something').expander(); // will work
$.something_from_non-jQuery_library_using_$_var(); // will work
```

You can also do this:

```
jQ = $.noConflict();
```

and then:

```
jQ('#something').expander(); // will work  
$.something_from_non-jQuery_library_using_$_var(); // will work
```

Comment: In addition to this, you can wrap all your code that uses $ in an anonymous function and call it with jQuery as param: (function($) { $('#something').expander(); })(jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
$('#something').show();
```

use,

```
jQuery.noConflict(true);
jQuery('#something').show();
```